# reactjs removeListener not working with es6 class

Tags: reactjs

Removing event listener on window does not work, almost as if it is not the same function when being added and removed. Thoughts for how to solve this? I also tried to abstract the `onScroll` method outside of the class and above in the file, no luck either.

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (__CLIENT__) {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this), true);
      console.log('mounting')
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this), true);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('unmount');
    if (__CLIENT__) {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll.bind(this), true);
    }
  }

  onScroll() {
    const { isLoading, isEndOfSurah } = this.props;
    console.log('here');

    if (isEndOfSurah) {
      return false;
    }

    if (!isLoading && !this.state.lazyLoading && window.pageYOffset > (document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight - 1000)) {
      // Reached the end.
      this.setState({
        lazyLoading: true
      });

      this.lazyLoadAyahs();
    }
  }
```

Comment: That's because it's not the same function when being added and removed. this.onScroll.bind returns a new function. Javascript is pass by reference, and functions are objects - so this.onScroll.bind(this) !== this.onScroll.bind(this)

Comment: @gabdallah makes sense! I had a feeling that's the problem but +1

Answer (score 2):

I'll elaborate on my comment. this.onScroll.bind(this) returns a new function, so each this.onScroll.bind(this) being used for each add/remove is a different function in memory. You can test this with === equality operator. Instead, bind the onScroll function in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this);
}
```

and then just use this.onScroll as it will have the desired this binding and will be the same function referenced in each event listener.

Comment: let me give it a try!